# Reading a csv file into a HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, hashmap

I've been trying to make a java program in which a tab delimited csv file is read line by line and the first column (which is a string) is added as a key to a hash map and the second column (integer) is it's value.

In the input file, there are duplicate keys but with different values so I was going to add the value to the existing key to form an ArrayList of values.

I can't figure out the best way of doing this and was wondering if anyone could help?

Thanks

EDIT: sorry guys, heres where i've got to with the code so far:
I should add the first column is the value and the second column is the key.

```
public class WordNet {

    private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> words;
    private final static String LEXICAL_UNITS_FILE = "wordnet_data/wn_s.csv";

    public WordNet() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        words = new HashMap<>();
        readLexicalUnitsFile();
    }

    private void readLexicalUnitsFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LEXICAL_UNITS_FILE));
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String columns[] = line.split("\t");
            if (!words.containsKey(columns[1])) {
                words.put(columns[1], new ArrayList<>());
            }

        }
        in.close();

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, without any code this is too broad a question.   You are expected to have attempted a solution before posting. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask]

Comment: code added guys apologies for the mistake

Comment: You split on the tabs, but only read the second column... You do know arrays are zero indexed, right?

Answer (score 2):

You are close

```
String columns[] = line.split("\t");
if (!words.containsKey(columns[1])) {
    words.put(columns[1], new ArrayList<>());
}
```

should be

```
String columns[] = line.split("\t");
String key = columns[0];                // enhance readability of code below
List<Integer> list = words.get(key);    // try to fetch the list
if (list == null)                       // check if the key is defined
{                                       //   if not
    list = new ArrayList<>();           //      create a new list
    words.put(key,list);                //      and add it to the map
}
list.add(new Integer(columns[1]));      // in either case, add the value to the list
```

In response to the OP's comment/question

> ... the final line just adds the integer to the list but not to the hashmap, does something need to be added after that?

After the statement

```
List<Integer> list = words.get(key);
```

there are two possibilities.  If `list` is non-null, then it is a *reference* to (not a copy of) the list that is already in the map.

If `list` is `null`, then we know the map does not contain the given key.  In that case we create a new empty list, set the variable `list` as a reference to the newly created list, and then add the list to the map for the key.

In either case, when we reach

```
list.add(new Integer(columns[1]));
```

the variable `list` contains a reference to an `ArrayList` that is already in the map, either the one that was there before, or one we just creatd and added.  We just add the value to it.

Comment: Does this actually add the key and value to the hashmap if the list isn't null?

Comment: The only way the list is null is if the key didn't exist in the map, in which case s new empty list is added with the key. Then the value is added to the list.

Comment: Ok but the final line just adds the integer to the list but not to the hashmap, does something need to be added after that?

Comment: See my updated answer.  If this solves your problem, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark. Thus future visitors will know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

> I should add the first column is the value and the second column is the key.

You could remplace the ArrayList declaration by a List declaration. But it is not very problematic.

Anyway, not tested but the logic should be such as :

```
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      String columns[] = line.split("\t");
      ArrayList<Integer> valueForCurrentLine = words.get(columns[1]);

      // you instantiate and put the arrayList once
      if (valueForCurrentLine==null){
          valueForCurrentLine = new  ArrayList<Integer>();
          words.put(columns[1],valueForCurrentLine);
      }

      valueForCurrentLine.add(columns[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Upvote to Jim Garrison's answer above. Here's a little more... (Yes, you should check/mark his answer as the one that solved it)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WordNet {

    private final Map<String, List<Integer>> words;
    private final static String LEXICAL_UNITS_FILE = "src/net/bwillard/practice/code/wn_s.csv";

    /**
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public WordNet() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        words = new HashMap<>();
        readLexicalUnitsFile();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void readLexicalUnitsFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LEXICAL_UNITS_FILE));
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String columns[] = line.split("\t");
            String key = columns[0];
            int valueInt;
            List<Integer> valueList;

            try {
                valueInt = Integer.parseInt(columns[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                continue;
            }

            if (words.containsKey(key)) {
                valueList = words.get(key);
            } else {
                valueList = new ArrayList<>();
                words.put(key, valueList);
            }

            valueList.add(valueInt);
        }

        in.close();
    }

    //You can test this file by running it as a standalone app....
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WordNet wn = new WordNet();
            for (String k : wn.words.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(k + " " + wn.words.get(k));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```